# Throughput Controller and Constant Throughput Timer don't work together in different thread groups

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

In my test plan I want to send N requests per second (RPS), where:

1. 20% from N I send to localhost:8888/api/journal (example address)
2. 80% to localhost:8888/api/simulation

I use `Throughput Controller` to implement percentage and `Constant Throughput Timer` to send N RPS.

When my requests in single Thread Group - it works well. Test plan screen below:

[image]

But if I place my requests in separate Thread Groups - `Throughput Controller` doesn't work. Like this:

[image]

**Throughput Controller config**: `Based on` is Percent Execution and `Throughput` is 20.0.

**Constant Throughput Timer config**: `Target Throughput` is 600.0 and `Calculate Throughput based on` is all active threads.

**2 similar Thread Groups**: 4 threads, 1 rampup, infinity loop count, 5 seconds duration.

At first screen I get ~10 RPS and 80/20 percentage, at second the same ~10 RPS but 50/50

What's wrong with second configuration? Thanks.

[jmx-file link](https://app.warp.dev/block/RppVetM2L1IM8Ix1gmeYvw) - you can copy it (changed to the second test plan)

Comment: Could you update the screenshots with sampler which is supposed to be executed in 80% of cases?

Comment: @GeorgeRylkov updated screenshots. did I understand you right?

Comment: Yes, but I can't really reproduce this behavior. Could you also provide the minimal .jmx which reproduces it?

Comment: @GeorgeRylkov added link with cat output from my jmx. you can copy it, sorry if it isn't the most comfortable way

Comment: This is what I get with JMeter 5.4.3:
80% - 40 samples, 20% -12 samples -- pretty close to expected values.
I had to change your localhost referencing requests to Dummy Samplers for the test (I don't have anything deployed on localhost).

Comment: @GeorgeRylkov goddamn, I gave you first test plan, sorry, it works. changed link to second test plan, it doesn't work for me

Comment: @GeorgeRylkov I think the reason is in the way I use Throughput Controller: it doesn't work as I expect where there is nothing but request under Throughput Controller in Thread Group. It needs more than 1 request in Thread Group to make percentage work. With single request Thread Group ignores percentage from Throughput Controller :(

Comment: Now I can also see it.
Throughput Controller works with a single request if you set the Loop Count in the Thread Group configuration to a finite amount though.

Since this behavior looks unexpected, you could probably open a bug:
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/

Comment: @GeorgeRylkov really. When I set finite amount in loop count, it works. I think it's quite unexpected. I've never opened bugs there, but I'll try. Thank you, you can make an answer here, I'll mark it as a desicion.
If to set finite loop amount, at first sight, it works as expected when `loop count` == `duration`, but roughly speaking

Comment: I think you can avoid providing duration in TG ('Specify Thread Lifetime') by having constant loop iteration duration ([see how to correctly organize it with timers](https://loadtestweb.info/2017/08/23/pacing/)).
You could also experiment with other Thread Groups such as Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary of discussion in comments section.

- This behavior seems unexpected and it's worth opening a bug with https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/.
- There are 2 workarounds:

  - Add additional request under **Throughput Controller**;
  - Set Loop Count to a finite number of iterations.